# Detect if user is identified and get the data

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, saml

I have a website with authentication by SAML.
I use the `aws-amplify` library on this site.
I need to know if the user is identified,
And if not - navigate him to the address of cognito which directs him to the login page of the SAML provider.
So, I used `aws-amplify` **v5** and wrote this code:

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(cognitoUser => {
  ...
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
  window.location.href = this.redirectLink;
});
```

When the user was identified - he reached the section inside the `then`,
And when he was not identified - he reached the section of the `catch`.

Now I'm trying to upgrade to **v6**,
And I see [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/angular/build-a-backend/auth/auth-migration-guide/#authcurrentauthenticateduser-deprecated) that the `currentAuthenticatedUser` function has been deprecated.
The article suggests using a combination of the `getCurrentUser` and `fetchAuthSession` API's.

I tried using both together and each of them separately,
But I couldn't get to the point where I can detect whether the user is identified or not.

The `getCurrentUser` function always falls to the `catch` with the error *"UserUnAuthenticatedException: User needs to be authenticated to call this API."*
And the `fetchAuthSession` function always returns empty properties.

I'm trying to figure out,
Am I doing something wrong?
Am I missing something?
Or is there really no way in this version to know if the user is identified?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,
I did it like this:

```
getCurrentUser().then(currentUser => {
  fetchAuthSession().then(cognitoUserSession => {
     this.doSomething(currentUser, cognitoUserSession);
  });
})
.catch(e => {
  signInWithRedirect({
    provider: { custom: "myIdentityProvider" }
  })
});
```